# How to reload multiDatesPicker in jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to get reload [multiDatesPicker](http://multidatespickr.sourceforge.net) jquery, I've tried below code:

```
$( "#datepicker" ).multiDatesPicker("refresh")
```

But it has not worked.

How can I reset the selected date value?

Comment: When you say reload what exactly are you trying to achieve? Reset the current date value?

Comment: Yes I want to reset selected date values.

Comment: http://multidatespickr.sourceforge.net/#method-resetDates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using:

```
$('#datepicker').multiDatesPicker('resetDates', 'disabled');
```

Answer (score 7):

To simply reset the dates to initial dates

$('#datepicker').multiDatesPicker('resetDates')

Answer (score 0):

You can destroy your multiDatesPicker and then re-create it.  I'm having to do this because I can't seem to add disabled dates dynamically.  Here is my example code snippet:

```
$('#datepicker').multiDatesPicker('destroy');

        var today = new Date();
        var y = today.getFullYear();
        $('#datepicker').multiDatesPicker({
            addDates: ['07/16/' + y]
            , addDisabledDates: ['07/30/' + y]
            , numberOfMonths: [2, 3]
            , altField: '#altField'
            , defaultDate: '7/1/' + y
        });
```